# removefromSuperView not removing subview

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm using a custom TableViewCell for my core data table view project. In the `layoutSubviews`method of the custom table view cell class, I create a subclass of UIView  called `MMCircles` and assign it to an _unreadIndicator property that gets added to the `contentView` of the custom table view cell, like this

```
   if(self.coolColor == [UIColor greenColor]){
          _unreadIndicator = [[MMCircles alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 18, 18) andColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
        _unreadIndicator.circleColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    }else if(self.coolColor == [UIColor redColor]){
          NSLog(@"unreadIndicator nil, creating red");
        _unreadIndicator = [[MMCircles alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 18, 18) andColor:[UIColor redColor]];
        _unreadIndicator.circleColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }else if ...

   [self.contentView addSubview:_unreadIndicator];
```

The end result is that I get circles of various colors added (in the list of table cells master table view controller) whenever I create a table view entry. Let's say for this example, I add a greenColor circle. If I touch the cell to edit what I've created, it opens in another view controller and I have the option of selecting another color for the _unreadIndicator of that cell. Let's say I try to make it `red`. What's actually happening is that the red circle is being added above the green circle. For example, if I set the size of the red circle smaller in the above method, you can clearly see the red ontop of the green. If I make the red the same size, it covers the green perfectly fine and no one knows any difference. However, I want to give the user the option to set the circle to `clearColor` and when that happens, there's obviously a problem, because the original color just shines through. Therefore I have to remove the _unreadIndicator (a subclass of UIView) rather than just cover it up.

**Trying to remove unreadIndicator**

I have tried several different ways to remove those circles, all without success. Before the above code, I added the following but it didn't work.

```
[_unreadIndicator removeFromSuperview];
_unreadIndicator = nil;
```

Also, `cellForRowAtIndexPath` (in the table view controller) gets called after a user edits a cell (which could include changing the color), therefore before I set the new color, I try to remove the unreadIndicator from superview. Again, this doesn't work

```
        switch ([joke.mood intValue]) {
         case 0:
         [cell.unreadIndicator removeFromSuperview];
         cell.coolColor = [UIColor greenColor]; //user has chosen green during edit, therefore remove old indicator
```

Finally, in the FetchedResultsController method `didChangeObject:AtIndexPath:forChangeType:newIndexPath`, I also try to remove the old circle color (without success). I tried it here because since the user is editing the table cell when trying to change the circle color (among other things), I'm assuming this code gets triggered

```
   case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:{
         Event *changedJoke = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        MMTableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
         cell.unreadIndicator = nil;
        [cell.unreadIndicator removeFromSuperview];
        cell.textLabel.text = changedJoke.mnemonic;

    }
```

The end result is that I can only cover up the circle, which isn't good enough, because I need to create the option of the circle not being there and `clearColor` can't cover up any of the other colors.

How can I remove this little subview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to reset `_unreadIndicator` without removing it in superview. So you lose the handle to the earlier view. Try removing view before creating and adding a new one.

```
 if(self.coolColor == [UIColor greenColor]){
      if(_unreadIndicator)
      {
         [_unreadIndicator removeFromSuperView];
      }

      _unreadIndicator = [[MMCircles alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 18, 18) andColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
    _unreadIndicator.circleColor = [UIColor greenColor];
}else if(self.coolColor == [UIColor redColor]){
      NSLog(@"unreadIndicator nil, creating red");
                if(_unreadIndicator)
      {
         [_unreadIndicator removeFromSuperView];
      }

    _unreadIndicator = [[MMCircles alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 18, 18) andColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    _unreadIndicator.circleColor = [UIColor redColor];
}else if ...

[self.contentView addSubview:_unreadIndicator];
```

Comment: If I do that, it says that _unreadIndicator doesn't clear selector removeFromSuperview.  (_unreadIndicator is a subclass of UIView called MMCircles). How should I change it to work? Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you explain what is the error you are encountering when you say "doesn't clear selector removeFromSuperview.". Since MMCircles is a subclass of UIView, it should inherit the properties of UIView and `removeFromSuper` view should be available.

Comment: sorry, I meant to say, _unreadIndicator doesnt' declare the selector removeFromSuperview. I agree with you about it should having that selector.See MMCircles is a subclass of UIView `@interface MMCircles : UIView` and in the tableViewCell I setup the property for unreadIndicator like so `@property(nonatomic, strong) MMCircles *unreadIndicator;` If it's setup like that (as a property of type MMCircles), shouldn't unreadIndicator have the selector removeFromSuperview?

Comment: ok it works, there was a misspelling in your code, it should be `removeFromSuperview`